# Why can we use EoSs of dense matter made in flat spacetime in solving the TOV equations

Tags: general-relativity

I was wondering why everyone use equations of state (EoS) of dense matter that are created using a flat spacetime in solving the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff equations, that are essentially developed in a curved spacetime. I found a paper explaining this using thermodynamic relations and was then curios if there are other reasons, maybe something I didn't understand from general relativity.

Comment: Because special relativity rules the "tangent space" to the spacetime manifold. In other words, spacetime is locally flat and, locally, GR is SR. In a neutron star, spacetime is practically flat at the scale of a local fluid element (this exact question is well discussed in the famous book of Glendenning https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-0491-3  ).